# How Dirbuster find the files within a directory? (Differentiating between files and directories)

Tags: penetration-test, kali-linux, information-gathering

I am writing the python code of DIRBUSTER tool in kali linux but I got stuck at finding files that lies within directories. So my question is how can I differentiate between Files and Directories while bruteforcing the directories recursively?

Comment: This is more like a programming question, it has nothing of "security" to be answered. Please try asking in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked a few times- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772537/7253829) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13116985/7253829)- within the general SO community. From what I can gather, the synopsis is that you cannot tell the difference between a file and a directory, at least without some fu, and even then there is no guarantee.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53262979/7253829) answer provided the most promise, and in summary states that you should just check for the presence of a file extension. And though this does not guarantee that a file extension will be present, it likely covers many use cases.